# Exit out of WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 in db_cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to exit out of the `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0` while performing a db_cursor?

I tried `SET @@FETCH_STATUS = 1`, but as i expected, an error. Help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`BREAK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181271.aspx) to exit a while loop.